# Change the layer of `show background rectangle`

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

The `backgrounds` tikz library defines `framed` (a.k.a. `show background rectangle`) which draws a background rectangle.

Now, when we have a picture that involves different layers (say, a `background` and a `main` layer), we wouldd like the frame of the picture to be drawn on the deeper layer (`background` in our case), or even deeper. However, it seems that the frame is shown on the `main` layer.

This MWE contains a single node on the background layer in a framed picture. The background rectangle fills the `main` layer, and therefore the node is not visible anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=blue!5}}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node {Hello world};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The tikz picture appears as a single filled rectangle, since the node is behind the background rectangle.]

---

Note: I know that I could reorder the layers to let the main at the bottom (like `main`, `background`, `mymain`), but if I can avoid to surround the important parts of the picture with a `mymain` layer, that would be better.

Comment: Without any testing, I would think the background rectangle is drawn last (when the size of the bounding box i known), so when you draw something else on the background first, the frame covers it. Can't you define a middle layer instead, putting that between background and main?

Comment: I just tried what you suggest, I added a `mybackground` intermediate layer and it works. N.B.: it seems that the `background` layer name is also the name used by the `backgrounds` library (i.e. if you have layers `truebackground`, `background`, `main`, the background rectangle is indeed in the `background` and not on `truebackground`). Thanks. I let you write your answer if you want the up-vote, or I'll do it latter otherwise :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'd kind of taken it for granted that the `backgrounds` library defines a layer called `background` ...) You are entirely correct that the library defines a `background` layer, the first thing it does is

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}%
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}%
```

So for your case it might make more sense to declare a `middle` layer, and do `\pgfsetlayers{background,middle, main}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=blue!25}}
\pgfdeclarelayer{middle}
\pgfsetlayers{background,middle, main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \node [fill=blue] {hello};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{middle}
    \node {Hello world};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```